# How to set minimum and maximum value of constraints on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, constraints

[image]
Hi, I made the above using the interface builder for the class size iPhone 6. However, when I switch to iPhone 5, Label B will overlap with imgC (which has a 'Align Trailing to' the box's right side).

In order of fixing this, I was thinking of setting the 30px constraint to have a minimum of 10px. I've tried making my imgB.leading constraint to label A <= 30px, instead of equals and added another imgB.leading constraint >= 10px but it seems to be stuck on 30px for the iPhone 5.

Is there a way where I can define a constraint to have a minimum and maximum value according to the screen size? Thanks!